# Directus error: foreign key constraint 'test_tes_foreign' are incompatible

Tags: database, directus, charset

In Directus version 10:

I set DB_CHARSET = "utf8mb4" in the .env file but I get this error when creating fields :

"alter table `test77777` add constraint `test77777_test_foreign` foreign key (`test`) references `directus_files` (`id`) on delete SET NULL - UNKNOWN_CODE_PLEASE_REPORT: Referencing column 'test' and referenced column 'id' in foreign key constraint 'test77777_test_foreign' are incompatible."

My database has the settings: charset utf8mb4 and collation utf8mb4_general_ci